# Importrange query: time duration condition under 10 seconds

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

I'm trying to make a query(importrange) of this google-sheet [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18OOzibH9rmuzNxOPo_EbZ1rhF32qESuvPa4x4pB1BmA/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to filter my data based on 3 conditions:

1. `Col5='GC' OR`
2. `Col5='CL' AND`
3. In `Col4` the time must be under 10 seconds.

I've been able to make a query on those data with a 1 minute time condition:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("18OOzibH9rmuzNxOPo_EbZ1rhF32qESuvPa4x4pB1BmA", "data!A1:Q"), 
 "where Col5 matches 'CL|GC' 
    and minute(Col4) < 1", 1)
```

but if I just change "minute(Col4) < 1" in "second(Col4) < 10" it does not work, as you can see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m1gNt2V5fGSAKQS-NOHuwP3_QxiYbXAm2XItoLuHpnc/edit?usp=sharing), where the first four rows are over the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("18OOzibH9rmuzNxOPo_EbZ1rhF32qESuvPa4x4pB1BmA", "data!A1:Q"), 
 "where Col5 matches 'CL|GC' 
    and minute(Col4) < 1 
    and second(Col4) < 10", 1)
```

[image: 0]